# Error while copy pasting ranges across sheets xlwings

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlwings, xlsm

I want to copy paste ranges for sheets in my  `.xlsm` workbook using xlwings.I want to maintain the source formatting and the leading single quote because of which I've used the `.copy` , `.paste` method.
I'm getting this error while trying to run the code  `(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Select method of Range class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)` after sheet 1 is successfully copied . The first sheet in the loop is copied properly but the above mentioned error is displayed after completion of sheet 1.
This is the code I used to copy paste the ranges across sheets :

```
wb = xw.Book('standalone.xlsm')
sheet_names = ['Sheet1','Sheet2']
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    sht=wb.sheets(sheet_name)
    sht.range('A1:A6').api.SpecialCells(12).copy
    sht.range('B1').select()
    sht.api.paste
    sht.api.Application.CutCopyMode=0
wb.save('standalone.xlsm')
wb.close()


PS :- I don't want to use `.value` method of copying ranges as it doesn't preserve source formatting and cells which start with single quote
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouwsy's answer works fine. Alternatively you can use pastespecial and with it you wont have to select the sheet

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('test.xlsx')
sheet_names = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    sht=wb.sheets(sheet_name)
    sht.range('A1:A6').api.SpecialCells(12).copy
    sht.range("R1").api.PasteSpecial("-4104")
    sht.api.Application.CutCopyMode=0
wb.save('standalone.xlsm')
wb.close()
```

**Update:**
Just found out xlwings already has a copy and paste method so a simple copy paste will be:

```
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    sht=wb.sheets(sheet_name)
    sht.range('A1:A6').copy()
    sht.range("R1").paste()
    sht.api.Application.CutCopyMode=0
```

This preserves source formatting. I cant find any other options for customising a copy and paste operation from the docs so I guess you'll still need the api for complete control.

Comment: I assume you are using SpecialCells to only get visible cells in case of filters or hidden cells, otherwise its not required for a simple copy paste

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So without the PasteSpecial the source formatting as is  by just using the `copy` `paste ` will be retained

Comment: Thanks again, If you feel it would help others facing the same issue you may upvote this question. Personally when I faced the issue I searched many SO  answers and none of the answers worked ( maybe because of different version or could be any other reason)

Answer (score 1):

The sheet must be active before you can select a range on it. Use `sht.select()`:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('test.xlsx')
sheet_names = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    sht = wb.sheets[sheet_name]
    sht.range('A1:A6').api.copy
    sht.select()
    sht['B1'].select()
    sht.api.paste
    wb.app.api.CutCopyMode = False
wb.save('test.xlsx')
wb.close()
```